# What should I set the full hostname to in plesk when hosting multiple domains?

Tags: web-hosting, dns, vps, plesk, mx

I have a VPS running Plesk (v11.5.30), on which I have multiple domains. I've found that I am having problems with emails sent from this server being tagged as spam.

On running a test with `www.mail-tester.com`

I get the following response:

```
We check if there is a mail server (A Record) behind your hostname localhost.localdomain.
You may want to publish a DNS record (A type) for the hostname localhost.localdomain or use a different hostname in your mail software.
```

Looking through my settings in Plesk I realise that I have the full host name (*Set in Server Management -> Tools & Settings -> General Settings -> Server Settings*) set to *localhost.localdomain*

My question is what should I set this to if I have multiple domains and would resetting it now fix my problem or has this value just been copied to somewhere in the mail system config files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here in case it helps anyone else.

Your hosting company should be able to provide you with the full name of your vps. It's probably visible somewhere in your control panel if you don't log direct into Plesk and is likely to be something like:

```
858442.vps-312.com
```

or

```
8abc-arc.yourdomain.com
```

Setting this to your full server name should fix this problem and (in my case at least) didn't effect any existing services.

On testing with www.mail-tester.com this changed by existing error:

```
We check if there is a mail server (A Record) behind your hostname localhost.localdomain.
You may want to publish a DNS record (A type) for the hostname localhost.localdomain or use a different hostname in your mail software.
```

to

```
Your hostname 858442.vps-312.com is assigned to a mail server.
```